# Line position after quickfix jump

Tags: quickfix

I'm using fzf's Rg command to populate QuickFix window with all search results. I also have my own mappings to `:cn` and `:cp` commands.

Everything is fine except one thing when I press mapped key for `:cn` command new buffer is opened and the line with searched text is positioned very close to the bottom edge of window. So if I searched for function name I need to scroll down to see function's body.

Is there any way to change this behavior? I would like to position line with found text somewhere near the middle of the window.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Afaik and can tell from `:help :cn`, this "new buffer" is not standard behavior. That said, `'switchbuf'` may influence the behavior. Can you check yours?

Comment: My `switchbuf` is "usetab". I not fully understand what do you mean saying "new buffer" is not standard behavior. What is standard behavior then?

Comment: Ah crud, I fear I’ve misread your Q. For some reason I thought you meant `:cn` was opening a new split, which would be bizarre. Nvm on that fromt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `zz` command and it’s siblings `zb` and `zt` are helpful positioning commands.

In this case, I would probably update your mapping to do `zz` (center cursor) after `:cnext`.